# Simple C++ Declaration Issue

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Why is this illegal, and what are some logical alternatives?

```
// State.h
class State {

public:
int a;
int b;
State z; //  <-- this is this problem

// ... Functions ...

};
```

Thank you.

Comment: `const State*` to keep a pointer of the object I guess?

Comment: Because of infinite recursion. How can an object contain one of itself?

Comment: *Why is this illegal* If it were permitted, think about how big one instance of this object would be...

Comment: illogical because this will end up in infinite number of state z. pointer  State* z is allow as it have no such limitation

Comment: It would be calling the constructor of State forever.

Comment: Are you trying to make `State` a singleton?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because, if it were allowed, every time you created an instance of `State` you would create an instance of `State` which would then create and instance of `State` and, well, that one needs a `State` too, so it creates an instance of `State`... and so on.

It would also send your compiler into infinite recursion while attempting to figure out `sizeof(State)`.  Be nice to your compiler.

Maintain a type of pointer instead and you will be fine.  On a side note, does it really make sense for a `State` to have its own (public) `State`?  I mean, I do love seeing lines of code like the following, but it could get ridiculous...

```
if(state.z->z->z->z->z->z->z->z == some_state) {
    // we found the right state!
}
```

If you're attempting to create a singleton, make your constructor private and add a static `get_instance` function which returns the one and only (static) instance of `State`.

Comment: The other alternative to this is to make `z` have `static` storage duration, which tends to suggest only one `State`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: I *just* added that, I think you may be right about the attempt at a singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Since `z` is a local variable, until you scan the entire `State` class, you can't know how much storage space you need to have.  Since `State` depends on itself, you will recurse infinitely.

Basically here's what happens in the compiler:

```
I see a class state.  Okay!
I now see a member variable a.  Okay!  Let's add 4 bytes to the size of our state
I now see a member variable b.  Okay!  Let's add 4 bytes to the size of our state
I now see a State.  Okay!  Let's see, our current size is 4 + 4, 
    now let's add the size of State to that, which is... um... ????
```

Pointers on the other hand have a size known at compile time(typically 4 bytes, but that depends on your architecture.)  That way, when you don't know the size of something, you can always have a pointer to it because the size is not important.

This is what happens in the compiler at that point:

```
I see a class state.  Okay!
I now see a member variable a.  Okay!  Let's add 4 bytes to the size of our state
I now see a member variable b.  Okay!  Let's add 4 bytes to the size of our state
I now see a State*.  Okay!   Let's add 4 bytes to the size of our state
I now see that class state has ended.  Its size is 4 + 4 + 4 = 12.
I can now do State z;  It will take 12 bytes of space.
```

Answer (score 1):

Illogical because this will end up in infinite number of **state z** because every instance of **z** will have another instance of **z** in it and so on . Pointer **State* z** is allow as it have no such limitation

Answer (score 0):

Use a `State *` instead.  This lets you end the recursion at some point.